# using __FUNCSIG__ in a macro expands it to be empty

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

I am using an API which return int error codes and I decided to build a wrapper error class :

```
class Error
{
    ...
 public:
     Error(int ErrC, const char* UserMessage, const char* FileName, int LineNumber, const char* Function);
     char * GetFunction();
    ...
}
```

I decided to venture into the world of macros and create a macro to instantiate the class for me :

```
#define API_ERROR(Code,MSG) API::Error(Code,MSG,__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCSIG__)
```

I then defined a Test function that is called by main

```
void TestFunc()
{
API::Error Error = API_ERROR(0,"Hello");
std::cout << Error.GetFunction();
}
```

Using the compiler option to output the post pre-processing results (Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocess to a file) yielded

```
void TestFunc()
{
API::Error Error = API::Error(o,"Hello","...\\main.cpp",30,);
std::cout << Error.GetFunction();
}
```

I think this does not work because `__FUNCSIG__` is only defined inside functions.
I have also tried

```
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(...) __VA_ARGS__ EMPTY()
#define API_ERROR(Code,MSG) API::Error(Code,MSG,__FILE__,__LINE__,DEFER(__FUNCSIG__))
```

But I think I misunderstood the author of the post.

Is there a way to make this work ?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community with the default MSVC++ compiler.

Comment: Meh can't test in Compiler Explorer as VS support seems to have dropped off :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this VS2019 predefined macro reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019)

> The `__FUNCSIG__` macro **isn't** expanded if you use the `/EP` or `/P` compiler option.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

If you preprocess your source then the `/EP` or `/P` flags would be set, and the macro won't be expanded. It will only be expanded when actually building your source.

The `__FUNCSIG__` macro will probably not be expanded by the preprocessor because it doesn't really know anything about C++ symbols. It might not even be a true preprocessor macro, and could be "expanded" (or replaced) at a later stage in compilation when C++ symbols are known.